# Read json data in d3 js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

```
var tabulate = function(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody')

    thead.append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d
        })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {
                    column: column,
                    value: row[column]
                }
            })
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.value
        })

    return table;
}
var columns = ['Client', 'Count', 'Count'];

d3.csv('test.csv', function(data) {

    //console.log(data[3]);
    tabulate(data, columns)
})
```

Text in my test.csv is

Client,Count
flipkart,809285
amazon,491189
snapdeal,469133
myntra,182708

what I need is to read data from a json I am getting from response while making an ajax call the json I am getting is

```
[
   {
      Client:"amazon",
      Count:"491189"
   },
   {
      Client:"flipkart",
      Count:"809285"
   },
   {
      Client:"snapdeal",
      Count:"469133"
   },
   {
      Client:"myntra",
      Count:"182708"
   }
];
```

I want to show the json in tabular format!!!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I want my data which is in .json format in tabular format, in the document for d3.js it is mentioned with .csv external file but I want it to be done using internal javascript json variable.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are after. If you are requesting JSON instead of CSV you could use [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) to process the data. When using these convenience methods keep in mind, that the callback is invoked with **two** parameters: the first being an error, if any, and the second your JSON response. For your purposes the callback should be like `d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {`

Comment: Thank altocumulus !!!

Comment: The json is not valid in jsonlint.com.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

D3 uses its [XHR module](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#xhr) to issues asynchronous request for retrieving data. However, in many cases you will find yourself not using `d3.xhr` directly, but one of the [convenience methods](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#convenience-methods) to make your life more easy.

If you are requesting JSON instead of CSV you could use [`d3.json(url[, callback])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) to process the data. When using these convenience methods keep in mind, that the callback is invoked with two parameters: the first being an error, if any, and the second your JSON response. For your purposes you could end up with something like this:

```
d3.json('test.json', function(error, data) {
    //console.log(data[3]);
    tabulate(data, columns)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below is a different approach but it works well.  You should wrap "Client" and "Count" in quotes BTW.

```
d3.select('body').append('table')

d3.json('data.js', function (data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var firstitem = data[i].Client;
        var seconditem = data[i].Count;

        d3.select('table').append('tr')
          .html('<td>' + firstitem + '</td>' + '<td>' + seconditem + '</td>')
    }
});
```

Here is data.js...

[
    {
        "Client": "amazon",
        "Count": "491189"
    },
    {
        "Client": "flipkart",
        "Count": "809285"
    },
    {
        "Client": "snapdeal",
        "Count": "469133"
    },
    {
        "Client": "myntra",
        "Count": "182708"
    }
]